# How do I handle a exception in a library in C#

Tags: c#

When I run the code it goes to the throw statement on the catch part rather at the place where the user calls it even after re-throwing.If i didn't catch and rethrow it goes into the function.How to prevent getting into the class library code and show the exception at the user level and prevent the user to view the library code.

```
public void Services(string hostName)
{
    try
    {
        if (hostName!=null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            FunctionThatThrowException(hostName);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: "prevent the user to view the library code." Huum? What is bad about being as precise as possible where an exception occured? Why do you want to hide that? Anyway your catch is completely useless, as it does not do anything except throwing **further**. If you really want to **rethrow**, create a new exception with the catched one as inner exception.

Comment: Your intention is unclear. Explain why you don't want users see those details. You're trapping yourself If your user bumped into an exception and you can't see anything.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The user can only change the value to this function.But the vs studio makes it possible for the user to view the whole code in the dll when the exeception occurs. Even the i throw further it goes to the catch statement rather than at the function call.

Comment: @LouisGo The user can see the exception but not the code right?.

Comment: @sabareesan_ravi I don't get it, user could only see the stacktrace of the thrown exception, which is NOT code itself, but it helps you if there is an exception you want to handle. Visual studio shows some of interfaces of dll when exception thrown, but it's not full, just signatures.

Comment: **end users** will never see your code in any form. They don't use visual studio. And you won't be giving them a copy of your source code, they only get a compiled application. But if you don't want them to see the full error message, then catch the exception, log the full error and stack trace somewhere, and then show a user-friendly error message instead. Users generally find technical error messages worrying anyway. Better to show them something they can understand

Comment: If or if not you can see the code of `FunctionThatThrows` has nothing to do with any exception, it´s a feature of the built-in decompiler (actually it´s a feature of .NET) and applies to any library built in .NET. If you want to prevent that generelly you may need some Obfuscator, that encrpyts your sourcecode to something harder to read.

Comment: @ADyson actually my users are dev-ops where they use my dll to create their own applications. So they use visual studio and make reference to the dll so how to prevent them viewing the code when the execption like argumentnullexception occurs

Comment: I see. You perhaps could have made that difference clear before. I think your question is answered more by HimBromBeere's last comment, then.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for your answer.Is Obfuscation is the right way to hide